# Should I upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04 immediately after it comes out?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

Are all my applications currently installed in my 14.04 going to be supported by 16.04 or do I have to wait for them to be ported over for 16.04?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to upgrade. Ubuntu 14.04 will be supported till 2019.

You will get an option to upgrade to 16.04.1 in August 2016.

The applications installed from Ubuntu repositories will be also upgraded.

Regarding other applications, nobody knows if all of them will work OK with the new release.